# How barrier component works in spring integration?

Tags: java, spring-integration, spring-integration-dsl

I am trying to understand following example: https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-integration-samples/tree/d8e71c687e86e7a7e35d515824832a92df9d4638/basic/barrier

and rewrite it using java DSL.

First of all I want to understand what is going in that example. Sure I've read [explanation from github](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-integration-samples/tree/d8e71c687e86e7a7e35d515824832a92df9d4638/basic/barrier) but I still don't get the idea. 
 I ask here because I know that SI team leads(authors of that example) answer all question tagged spring-integration.

server configuration:

```
<int-http:inbound-gateway request-channel="receiveChannel"
                            path="/postGateway"
                            error-channel="errorChannel"
                            supported-methods="POST"/>

    <int-http:inbound-gateway request-channel="createPayload"
                            path="/getGateway"
                            error-channel="errorChannel"
                            supported-methods="GET"/>

    <int:transformer input-channel="createPayload" output-channel="receiveChannel" expression="'A,B,C'" />

    <int:channel id="receiveChannel" />

    <int:header-enricher input-channel="receiveChannel" output-channel="processChannel">
        <int:header name="ackCorrelation" expression="headers['id']" />
    </int:header-enricher>

    <int:publish-subscribe-channel id="processChannel" />

    <int:chain input-channel="processChannel" order="1">
        <int:header-filter header-names="content-type, content-length" />
        <int:splitter delimiters="," />
        <int-amqp:outbound-channel-adapter amqp-template="rabbitTemplate"
            exchange-name="barrier.sample.exchange" routing-key="barrier.sample.key"
            confirm-ack-channel="confirmations"
            confirm-nack-channel="confirmations"
            return-channel="errorChannel"
            confirm-correlation-expression="#this"/>
    </int:chain>

    <!-- Suspend the HTTP thread until the publisher confirms are asynchronously received -->

    <int:barrier id="barrier" input-channel="processChannel" order="2"
        correlation-strategy-expression="headers['ackCorrelation']"
        output-channel="transform" timeout="10000" />

    <int:transformer input-channel="transform" expression="payload[1]" />

    <!-- Aggregate the publisher confirms and send the result to the barrier release channel -->

    <int:chain input-channel="confirmations" output-channel="release">
        <int:header-filter header-names="replyChannel, errorChannel" />
        <int:service-activator expression="payload" /> <!-- INT-3791; use s-a to retain ack header -->
        <int:aggregator>
            <bean class="org.springframework.integration.samples.barrier.AckAggregator" />
        </int:aggregator>
    </int:chain>

    <int:channel id="release" />

    <int:outbound-channel-adapter channel="release" ref="barrier.handler" method="trigger" />

    <!-- Consumer -> nullChannel -->

    <int-amqp:inbound-channel-adapter channel="nullChannel"
        queue-names="barrier.sample.queue"
        connection-factory="rabbitConnectionFactory" />

    <!-- Infrastructure -->

    <rabbit:queue name="barrier.sample.queue" auto-delete="true" />

    <rabbit:direct-exchange name="barrier.sample.exchange" auto-delete="true">
        <rabbit:bindings>
            <rabbit:binding queue="barrier.sample.queue" key="barrier.sample.key" />
        </rabbit:bindings>
    </rabbit:direct-exchange>
```

As far I understand there are 3 parties:

- client
- server
- rabbitMq

Client sends `A,B,C` to the server

```
RequestGateway requestGateway = client.getBean("requestGateway", RequestGateway.class);
String request = "A,B,C";
System.out.println("\n\n++++++++++++ Sending: " + request + " ++++++++++++\n");
String reply = requestGateway.echo(request);
```

Server accepts that request:

```
<int-http:inbound-gateway request-channel="receiveChannel"
                        path="/postGateway"
                        error-channel="errorChannel"
                        supported-methods="POST"
```

then some values are added to the message headers:

```
<int:header-enricher input-channel="receiveChannel" output-channel="processChannel">
        <int:header name="ackCorrelation" expression="headers['id']" />
    </int:header-enricher>
```

some processing:

```
<int:chain input-channel="processChannel" order="1">
        <int:header-filter header-names="content-type, content-length" />
        <int:splitter delimiters="," />
        <int-amqp:outbound-channel-adapter amqp-template="rabbitTemplate"
            exchange-name="barrier.sample.exchange" routing-key="barrier.sample.key"
            confirm-ack-channel="confirmations"
            confirm-nack-channel="confirmations"
            return-channel="errorChannel"
            confirm-correlation-expression="#this"/>
    </int:chain>
```

If I am not mistaken - message splitted by `,` so we have 3 messages `A` `B` and `C` and send into rabbitMq exchange `barrier.sample.exchange` with `keybarrier.sample.key`

That so. Next steps unclear for me. Could you please clarify ?

**P.S.**

I understand that we want to await all ACKs messages from rabbit to be sure that messages we delivered to the rabbit and when we get all ACKs from rabbit we want to answer to client. But I don't understand SI components definition which lead to that result. Could you provide any schema/picture/explanation how it happens ?

**More concrete questions:**

Why do we need enrich headers and how we do it ?

<del>What is the aim of **receiveChannel** ?</del> - stupid question

Where are 2 http services - `/postGateway` and `/getGateway`. `/postGateway` is used for getting msg from client, splitting into parts, send to the rabbit, get Acks and then answer to the client back. But what is the aim of `/getGateway` ?

### P.S.

For now my flow declration looks like this:

```
    @Bean
public IntegrationFlow integrationFlow() {
    return IntegrationFlows.from(Http.inboundGateway("/spring_integration_post")
            .requestMapping(m -> m.methods(HttpMethod.POST))
            .requestPayloadType(String.class))
            .enrich(enricherSpec -> {
                enricherSpec.header("correlationId", 1); //or ackCorrelationId ?
            })
            .split(s -> s.applySequence(false).get().getT2().setDelimiters(","))
            .log()
            //.barrier(1000L) is it correct place for barrier?
            .log()
            .handle(Amqp.outboundAdapter(amqpTemplate())
                    .exchangeName("barrierExchange")
                    .routingKey("barrierKey"))
            .get();
}
```

I don't know how to use barrier here.

From server side everything is partially working - I see messages in queue(on rabbitMq web interface) but from client side I started to see following stacktrace:

```
2019-08-28 22:38:43.432 ERROR 12936 --- [ask-scheduler-8] o.s.integration.handler.LoggingHandler   : org.springframework.messaging.MessageHandlingException: HTTP request execution failed for URI [http://localhost:8080/spring_integration_post]; nested exception is org.springframework.web.client.HttpServerErrorException$InternalServerError: 500 null, failedMessage=GenericMessage [payload=6, headers={id=36781a7f-3d4f-e17d-60e6-33450c9307e4, timestamp=1567021122424}]
    at org.springframework.integration.http.outbound.HttpRequestExecutingMessageHandler.exchange(HttpRequestExecutingMessageHandler.java:171)
    at org.springframework.integration.http.outbound.AbstractHttpRequestExecutingMessageHandler.handleRequestMessage(AbstractHttpRequestExecutingMessageHandler.java:289)
    at org.springframework.integration.handler.AbstractReplyProducingMessageHandler.handleMessageInternal(AbstractReplyProducingMessageHandler.java:123)
    at org.springframework.integration.handler.AbstractMessageHandler.handleMessage(AbstractMessageHandler.java:169)
    at org.springframework.integration.dispatcher.AbstractDispatcher.tryOptimizedDispatch(AbstractDispatcher.java:115)
    at org.springframework.integration.dispatcher.UnicastingDispatcher.doDispatch(UnicastingDispatcher.java:132)
    at org.springframework.integration.dispatcher.UnicastingDispatcher.dispatch(UnicastingDispatcher.java:105)
    at org.springframework.integration.channel.AbstractSubscribableChannel.doSend(AbstractSubscribableChannel.java:73)
    at org.springframework.integration.channel.AbstractMessageChannel.send(AbstractMessageChannel.java:453)
    at org.springframework.integration.channel.AbstractMessageChannel.send(AbstractMessageChannel.java:401)
    at org.springframework.messaging.core.GenericMessagingTemplate.doSend(GenericMessagingTemplate.java:187)
    at org.springframework.messaging.core.GenericMessagingTemplate.doSend(GenericMessagingTemplate.java:166)
    at org.springframework.messaging.core.GenericMessagingTemplate.doSend(GenericMessagingTemplate.java:47)
    at org.springframework.messaging.core.AbstractMessageSendingTemplate.send(AbstractMessageSendingTemplate.java:109)
    at org.springframework.integration.endpoint.SourcePollingChannelAdapter.handleMessage(SourcePollingChannelAdapter.java:234)
    at org.springframework.integration.endpoint.AbstractPollingEndpoint.doPoll(AbstractPollingEndpoint.java:390)
    at org.springframework.integration.endpoint.AbstractPollingEndpoint.pollForMessage(AbstractPollingEndpoint.java:329)
    at org.springframework.integration.endpoint.AbstractPollingEndpoint.lambda$null$1(AbstractPollingEndpoint.java:277)
    at org.springframework.integration.util.ErrorHandlingTaskExecutor.lambda$execute$0(ErrorHandlingTaskExecutor.java:57)
    at org.springframework.core.task.SyncTaskExecutor.execute(SyncTaskExecutor.java:50)
    at org.springframework.integration.util.ErrorHandlingTaskExecutor.execute(ErrorHandlingTaskExecutor.java:55)
    at org.springframework.integration.endpoint.AbstractPollingEndpoint.lambda$createPoller$2(AbstractPollingEndpoint.java:274)
    at org.springframework.scheduling.support.DelegatingErrorHandlingRunnable.run(DelegatingErrorHandlingRunnable.java:54)
    at org.springframework.scheduling.concurrent.ReschedulingRunnable.run(ReschedulingRunnable.java:93)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:515)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run$$$capture(FutureTask.java:264)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.run(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:304)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1128)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:628)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:834)
Caused by: org.springframework.web.client.HttpServerErrorException$InternalServerError: 500 null
    at org.springframework.web.client.HttpServerErrorException.create(HttpServerErrorException.java:79)
    at org.springframework.web.client.DefaultResponseErrorHandler.handleError(DefaultResponseErrorHandler.java:124)
    at org.springframework.web.client.DefaultResponseErrorHandler.handleError(DefaultResponseErrorHandler.java:102)
    at org.springframework.web.client.ResponseErrorHandler.handleError(ResponseErrorHandler.java:63)
    at org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate.handleResponse(RestTemplate.java:778)
    at org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate.doExecute(RestTemplate.java:736)
    at org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate.execute(RestTemplate.java:710)
    at org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate.exchange(RestTemplate.java:598)
    at org.springframework.integration.http.outbound.HttpRequestExecutingMessageHandler.exchange(HttpRequestExecutingMessageHandler.java:165)
    ... 30 more
```

Answer (score 2):

It's quite straightforward; it's not clear what you don't understand.

- we get a request from http
- we add a correlation header to the message (header enricher)
- we send 3 messages to rabbitmq
- we need to wait for confirmations - so the HTTP thread is suspended in the barrier
- asynchronously the 3 confirmations come back
- we aggregate the responses into a single message (using the correlation header)
- we send that message to the barrier which releases the HTTP thread

The `receiveChannel` is the input channel to header enricher.

You need to add the flow to receive the confirmations, aggregate, and trigger the barrier.

Comment: You need to add another flow to receive the confirmations, aggregate, and trigger the barrier.

Comment: Ok. thx - high level picture is clear but stil have several questions. 1. Let's start from enricher. As you can see my enricher is hardcoded and should be rewriten in some way. Is it correct that A, B and C messages should have the same correlationId(or ackCorrelationId ?) . 2. As far I understand I have to initiialize barrier with amount of splitted messages in some way. I have no idea how to do it

Comment: I also updated last part of the topic - please take a look.

Comment: The correlation id must be unique - that's why I used the `id` header for the correlation id in the pre-split message. Yes, the header will be copied to the splits. No; the aggregator handles all that the splitter adds sequence information to the splits and the default release strategy uses it to decide when the group is complete.

Comment: `>I also updated last part of the topic -` Why do you need a barrier at all? Your handler doesn't appear to do something that generates asynchronous messages that you need to wait for.

Comment: I need barrier because I want to learn how it works and I try to repeat your sample but via DSL. I am going to start writing the second flow soon but I want to understan other stuff first

Comment: I am really sorry but I don't  understand your comment related to the correlation id. How unique shold it be? should it be the same for all parts(A, B, C) ?. Before splitting mesage you save some ID in the header and call it **ackCorellationId**

Comment: The barrier is not going to work until the async replies flow is there; something has to call the barrier's trigger to release the thread. The incoming message has an `id` header which is always unique; so I used it as the header on which I want to correlate the acks coming back from rabbit for the inbound message - we might be dealing with multiple inbound messages concurrently. I suggest you read about [the aggregator](https://docs.spring.io/spring-integration/docs/5.1.7.RELEASE/reference/html/#aggregator) (and splitter) to understand more.

Comment: The barrier is advanced; it would be better to understand more basic components first.

Comment: I just explore all samples from basic folder one by one. I've already spent a lot of time(my and even your) to understand and it would be sorry to switch to another example now. I am sure i able to understand it with your help) At least I am familiar with java sychronizators. It should be smt like this

Comment: I think I need to finish sync flow first(withour barrier)

Comment: So all splitted messages which were splitted from the same client message will have the **same**(without any postfixes) correlationId?(true or false) how can I achieve it using DSl ?

Comment: Correct - the splitter will simply copy the headers from the pre-split message (the one from the enricher). There is nothing more to do, except implement the aggregator flow - you can't get half of this app to work without the other half.

Comment: current version of flow doesn't return anything to the client  - last stacktrace from the topic - how to fix it ? How to implement enricher to copy "id" header  using DSL?

Comment: Moreover line from xml config **<int:transformer input-channel="createPayload" output-channel="receiveChannel" expression="'A,B,C'" />** looks suspicious because it contains **A,B,C**

Comment: You have to enable confirms in the connection factory and adapter - see the XML. See `connectionFactory.setPublisherConfirms(true);` in the sample application. WIth modern versions of boot you can do it in application properties.

Comment: That is only for the second gateway (so you can do GET from a browser). For the first gateway. A,B,C is sent in a POST from the client side (HTTP adapter via a messaging gateway). The admins here don't like extended commentary on answers - see **Please avoid extended discussions in comments.** above.

Comment: I just pushed [a commit to move the connection factory settings to the properties](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-integration-samples/commit/4c4e1bc0960b025b099a1c4410da11108b55b0ec).

Comment: I already have **setPublisherConfirms(true)** https://github.com/gredwhite/spring-integration/blob/master/complete/src/main/java/barrier/server/Config.java

Comment: I've already asked about 'second endpoint' aim in the topic. Could we proceed our conersation in the chat ?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/198611/discussion-between-gary-russell-and-gstackoverflow).